# How to deploy a new version of the contract?

Tags: solidity, truffle

Probably this is not possible, but I still have to ask.

Let me follow the example created in `truffle init`. It contains a contract called `MetaCoin.sol`. Say,

1. I have deployed it on the network (the first version of it).
2. Then I have extended it with a `foo()` method.
3. Now I want to deploy a new modified version of the contract with the same name MetaCoin but the new code of it. Is there a way of doing it?

As the hint there is a contract called `Migrations.sol` which has a method called `upgrade()`:

`function upgrade(address new_address) restricted {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
  }`

that sets a new address for the code of the contract. Is there a better way of doing versioning or upgrades (deploy rollouts) of the coins code?

Comment: Probably the way to answer it is written [here](https://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/contracts/#method-deployed) by calling `new()` as in  `..You can use this method to deploy a completely new instance of a contract onto the network.` Maybe I simply misunderstand the whole instances thing.

Comment: Adding alternative link to [migrations](https://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/develop/getting_started/migrations/#command) in truffle.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you should use **truffle(.cmd) migrate --reset** to redeploy it on the network.
everytime you run migrate an new address and new contract is created.

(sorry reputatio too low to comment)

Comment: I've upvoted this answer to give you +10 rep.

Comment: reset sounds like the wrong name :/ but I think it's the way to go. What if I have 10 contracts and I only changed 1, would reset deploy 10 of them or the one changed?

Comment: marking as an answer as it seems a correct one after some time of working with truffle framework. I would in general recommend another security framework called https://openzeppelin.org/

Answer (score 3):

Since google lists this question pretty far on top by searching for "truffle deploy new contract" and accepted answer does redeploy all(!) contracts I post following solution for redeploying a single contract:

You need to use both flags --f NUMBER and --to NUMBER with the command "truffle migrate" ([look here](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/truffle-commands))

Example, for redeploying a contract with the migration file "5_mycontract_migration.js":

```
truffle migrate --f 5 --to 5
```

Answer (score 1):

To redeploy a single contract MyContract:

- create a new migration with
  `truffle create migration my_new_migration_name`
- in the new migration file (found in the migrations folder), you can redeploy using `deployer.deploy(MyContract)`

You can also use the truffle deploy "force" feature:
`truffle deploy -f migration_name`
reruns a specific migration

Answer (score 0):

You can not "update" a contract, once you deploy it , it is in the chain block.

But you can redeploy it (with a new contract address).

Use `truffle migrate --reset` to recreate already migrated contract.
Or just copy the old migration file and rename it to a new migration.